# How to aggregate real-time geolocation of user using S2 Geometry Library at different zoom levels?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, geospatial, aggregation, s2

I am working on an idea where every user (~10,000 Concurrent Users) are streaming their geo-location. I want to **aggregate users** and display on a map with one single pointer at different zoom levels after that If the user zoom in or zoom out then that pointer also distributed and aggregates users according to that particular zoom level of the map using **S2 Cells**.

At the beginning any user will see **globe** just like google earth after that If user zoom in or zoom out at certain position then we need to aggregate users according to that **zoom level** of the user(current).

In the beginning, I have planned to use some streaming tool like **Kafka** and for stream processing tools like **flink** and from front end I will stream user data e.g **latitude, longitude, and boundaries longitude and latitude from current zoom level** and In the backend, I just check into stream data If users **lat, long** are falls in **boundary lat, long** then just return that user with his lat, long and just pinpoint on the map, but this is not that I want to do, **I want to aggregate all user at the certain region** and display **only one pointer** after that If I zoom Inside that pointer then It will distribute the pointer and show some others pointers. If I just zoom in at the max level of the map then users show individual.

I want to work on **< 30 seconds** old data aggregation.

At the frontend, I am using Mapbox to show users on a map.
I want to know, how can I use S2 Library Cells to aggregate data and I am also looking for how to make the balance of Mapbox Zoom Levels and S2 Zoom Levels.

[image]

The output something like that points

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Kafka or Streaming other than ingestion. Various Javascript frameworks (start with D3) already provide such a feature, and you'd query the data out of a database/API with query filters around the box of display coordinates, not directly from a stream

Comment: Actually I am creating a mobile application not web application. Can you please explain which real time database I can use to query.

Comment: So you know, a PWA is both a mobile app and a web app. Javascript can be loaded into a webview. You can write your code in Flutter or React Native... Still, Javascript is far more along with visuals than any mobile sdk I know of... And you wouldn't query a database directly from mobile, you'd often build a web API first. Database isn't really important here (forget real time requirements), as long as it can do geoquery... Popular options here could be Mongo or Postgres